# Does anyone know a command to determine the services depending on the DNS Client?

Tags: windows, cmd, virtualization

I need a command to be used in cmd to check the dependent services of the dns client if anyone knows would appreciate it because in the graphical interface I can check but I am missing through the command line

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help!

https://kevincurran.org/com320/labs/dhcp.html

Type sc query and press Enter to view the status of all running services. To view the status of DHCP, type sc query dhcp and press Enter, and to view the status of DNS, type sc query dnscache and press Enter.